# Non Uniform Date columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

my dataframe looks like:

```
a = DataFrame({'clicks': {0: 4020, 1: 3718, 2: 2700, 3: 3867, 4: 4018, 5:  
     4760, 6: 4029},'date': {0: '23-02-2016', 1: '24-02-2016', 2: '11/2/2016',
     3: '12/2/2016', 4: '13-02-2016', 5: '14-02-2016', 6: '15-02-2016'}})
```

Rows have 2 different formattings.

The format I need is:

```
a = DataFrame({'clicks': {0: 4020, 1: 3718, 2: 2700, 3: 3867, 4: 4018,
5: 4760, 6: 4029}, 'date': {0: '2/23/2016',1: '2/24/2016', 2: '2/11/2016',
3: '2/12/2016', 4: '2/13/2016', 5: '2/14/2016', 6: '2/15/2016'}})
```

So far I managed to open the csv in Excel as text data, UTF-8 format and then choose a MDY formatting for the date column. Moreover I apply:

```
a['date'] = a['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y'))
```

How can I efficiently do that in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to `datetime` using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then call [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to get it in the format you want:

```
In [21]:
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
a

Out[21]:
   clicks        date
0    4020  02/23/2016
1    3718  02/24/2016
2    2700  02/11/2016
3    3867  02/12/2016
4    4018  02/13/2016
5    4760  02/14/2016
6    4029  02/15/2016
```

if the column is already `datetime` dtype then you can skip the `to_datetime` step